# Reduce list of object into Immutable map with lambda

Tags: java, lambda, immutability

I have a list of `Person` object. All person has a unique id, but the person's name can be the same.

```java
Person {
    String id,
    String name,
}
```

I want to convert this array of persons into `ImmutableMap<String, ImmutableSet<String>>`. The key of the map should be the user's name, the immutable set contains the ids of specific user's name.

I know how to do it using HashMap and HashSet:

```java
for (person : personList) {
    String id = person.id;
    String name = person.name;
    if (!hashMap.containsKey(name)) {
        hashMap.put(name, new HashSet<String>());
    }
    hashMap.get(name).add(id);
}
```

I want to know how to do it using ImmutableMap, ImmutableSet with lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible solution.

First, generate some data.  Three names and 18 ids. Put them in a list.

```java
      Random r = new Random();
      int[] ids = r.ints(1000, 1, 1000).distinct().limit(18).toArray();
      int id = 0;
      List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();
      for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
         for (String name : List.of("Bob", "Joe", "Mary")) {
            people.add(new Person(name, ids[id++]));
         }
      }
```

Now creating the map.

1. Use `groupingBy` to create a `key` pointing to a `collection`.  The key is the 
   name and the collection is the map.
2. The `collection(a set)` holds the `ids`

```java
      Map<String, Set<Integer>> nameToID =
            Collections.unmodifiableMap(people.stream().collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getName, Collectors.mapping(
                        Person::getID, Collectors.toUnmodifiableSet()))));
```

Print them.

```java
      nameToID.entrySet().forEach(
            e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " -> " + e.getValue()));

   }
}
```

Here is the Person class with some additional methods and a constructor.

```java
class Person {
   String name;
   int    id;

   public Person(String name, int id) {
      this.name = name;
      this.id = id;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public int getID() {
      return id;
   }

   public String toString() {
      return "(" + name + "," + id + ")";
   }
}
```